# convert bigint to nvarchar by format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-convert

How can I convert `bigint` to `nvarchar` using the following scheme:

- `1` converts to `0001`
- `123` converts to `0123`

Comment: 123 should convert to 0123 or 0125?

Comment: @SWeko Thank you for your notification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a possible solution:

```
declare @i bigint
SET @i = 125
select right( '0000' + ltrim( str( @i ) ), 4 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Slight variation of `danihp`'s, but using the `REPLICATE` function.

```
DECLARE @aVar bigint
SELECT @aVar = 123;
SELECT RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 4) + LTRIM(STR(@aVar)), 4)
```

Will return `0123`